# I get an empty file for .har

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, har

I was always able to generate a .har file to help devs for troubleshooting issues. But recently I just get an empty file for that!
P.S. I use Chrome.

Comment: Same here, I am using Version 66.0.3359.117 (Official Build) (64-bit) on MAC. Have you found out anything else?

Answer (score 0):

Does this happen on all websites? If not, wait patiently for file to export. Sometimes there are plenty of requests to save (for example some web socket stuff) and it takes time. Give it few minutes.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Firefox 95 and I am having the same problem.
I noticed that the page has an problem will will not load completely.  The loading indicator in the tab keeps animating.

I tried disabling cache and force refresh the page to get it to load completely.
After that, I was able to get a HAR file.

[image]